# Javascript & Titanium - Can't read XML text nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

My code is very simple: I'm trying to parse the following XML: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xml-samples/bookstore.xml

But when I try to print data, I obtain an array of null (however the length is correct).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    var xml = this.responseXML;
    //get the book nodelist from our response xml object
    var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("book");
    //create empty data array
    var data=[];
    //loop each book in the xml
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        //obtain the title
        var str=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text;
        //add the title to our data array
        data.push(str);
    }

    console.log(data);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
var lng = endLocation.getElementsByTagName('lng').item(0).childNodes.item(0).nodeValue;
```

instead of:

```
var lng = endLocation.getElementsByTagName('lng').item(0).text;
```